# Mysql How to insert all updated old and new rows by using trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, logging, triggers

I am creating a log table by using trigger in mysql

I want to insert only updated `old value`, `new value` and `row name` to the `log_table` when the `specific target_table id` is update.

### target_table

| id | row1 | row2 | row3 | row4 | row5 | row6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | item | item | item | item | item | item |

### log_table

| past | new | row_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | null | null |

This is my rough sql code.

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_sync 
AFTER UPDATE ON (target_table) FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO (
    (log_table).past, (log_table).current, (log_table).name 
)
VALUES (OLD.(row_item) , NEW.(row_item) , (target_table).(row_name))
FROM log_table
WHERE NEW.(target_id) = (id);
END
```

What should I write in the OLD, NEW and row_name sentence?
If not, How should I write the trigger code? thank you for reading my questions.

Comment: What problem are you having? If you have a syntax error message publish it in full if it fails on execution puBlish the error message etc

Comment: Beauty kills syntax correctness. Remove excess brackets and set correct ones (look for INSERT syntax).

Comment: You code is too simple you have to test which column has changed (why you have chosen to call them row1 to row n is baffling) and code cannot be dynamic..you cannot add columns without changing trigger.

Comment: What should I write in the OLD, NEW and row_name sentence?

Comment: You need a bunch of if statement to test which column has changed and gather the appropriate new and old values  FOR clarity please publish table definitions.